# Regex match 8-digit phone with optional hyphens between each digit

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I want to extract 8-digit numbers from a paragraph. It can contain a single optional hyphen anywhere between digits and MUST start with 6 or 7, so the following should match:

```
71234567
6-1234567
7-123-4567
61-23-45-67
7-1-2-3-4-5-6-7
...
```

I'd like to extract only the digits, so when matching 7-1-2-3-4-5-6-7, it returns only 71234567.

I tried to hardcode it like this:

```
[\b\D]([67]-?\d-?\d-?\d-?\d-?\d-?\d-?\d)[\b\D]
```

and then removing manually the hyphen later, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't omit chars from a matched substring. You need to postprocess your matches. `[x.replace('-', '') for x in re.findall(r'\b[67](?:-?\d){7}\b', data)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't omit chars from a matched substring. You need to postprocess your matches.

Also, note that `[\b\D]` matches a *backspace* char or a non-digit char. `[\b]` does not match a *word boundary*.

You can use

```py
numbers = [x.replace('-', '') for x in re.findall(r'\b[67](?:-?\d){7}\b', data)]
# or, if the number can be glued to a letter or underscore
numbers = [x.replace('-', '') for x in re.findall(r'(?<!\d)[67](?:-?\d){7}(?!\d)', data)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mPV7Ap/1/). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `[67]` - `6` or `7`
- `(?:-?\d){7}` - seven occurrences of an optional `-` and a digit sequences
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7wAMxu):

```py
import re
data = '71234567 6-1234567 7-123-4567  61-23-45-67  7-1-2-3-4-5-6-7'
print([x.replace('-', '') for x in re.findall(r'\b[67](?:-?\d){7}\b', data)])
# => ['71234567', '61234567', '71234567', '61234567', '71234567']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm and the explanation is very useful.